# Multi server processing

Tags: php, node.js, parallel-processing, rabbitmq, celery

I have the following goal to complete.
Suppose I have the following set

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

And then 3 conditions

```
the first number must be even
the second number must be odd
the sum of first 3 numbers must be 12
```

To find the proper set my goal is to generate random sets and check if they meet the conditions.

```
1,3,2,5,4,6 - 0 conditions
2,4,3,5,6,1 - 1 condition
2,3,4,5,6,1 - 2 conditions
4,5,3,2,6,1 - 3 conditions. All conditions met, this is our set
```

This is a very basic example, it will be a lot more data and a lot more conditions. Why am I using this way to find the set? Because having so many rules will be impossible to find the proper set and sometimes is impossible to find a set to meet all conditions so I will have a validation that will allow, for example, a set of more than 80% conditions met.

So I want to process this on multiple servers until I found a valid set(s). Probably I will use Amazon s3 instances.

I was looking into RabbitMQ and Celery but as far as I understood, they're more like a queue setup, not parallel processing. Also, I will probably need to write this in PHP and node.js

I was also thinking to have a master server and slave servers. The slave servers will start to generate and validate sets and will send the result to master using rabbit me. Once a set is found, the master will shut down the slave servers.

Not sure if this is the proper approach (both professionally and optimization wise)

What software should I use and what is a good way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you can't generate only the valid sets based on the given rules?

Comment: +1 to @Cristy 's comment. Also, do you need all correct sets, just one, or a certain number of correct sets? That will influence the solution quite a bit

Comment: @Cristy there are so many variables that will be impossible to do that. We tried and other people tried but it gets so complicated.

Comment: @AlexBuyny i will probably try to find more. I will get probably top 5 results and then we will chose the set that fits us best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was also thinking to have a master server and slave servers. The slave servers will start to generate and validate sets and will send the result to master using rabbit me. Once a set is found, the master will shut down the slave servers.

I think your approach is going to work. RabbitMQ is about messages, message passing is a tool to organize parallel processing.

Your Task Generator (master) sends tasks (RabbitMQ messages) into the [worker queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html). Your processors (slaves) are subscribed to the queue. They can fetch task messages from the queue and start generating sets. Once generated, they send the result back to the master node. It can issue subsequent tasks based on what results it receives, ie `generate sets of higher value from now` or `enough, stop work` (those ones should go into different `command` topic that slaves are also subscribed to).